# MaxPooling operation on temporal data - select signal with the highest amplitude

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Is there any clean way to perform Maxpooling operation on temporal data (i.e. signal with highest amplitude will be the output).

For example,

```py
# sample four sin signals
a = 2*tf.math.sin(tf.linspace(0, 10, 200))
b = 0.1*tf.math.sin(2*tf.linspace(0, 10, 200))
c = 3*tf.math.sin(0.5*tf.linspace(0, 10, 200))
d = 1*tf.math.sin(5*tf.linspace(0, 10, 200))
# stack the signals
data = tf.stack([a, b, c, d], -1)
# reshape to appropriate timeseries of 2D feature-maps
# (batch_size, sequence length, feature_dim1, feature_dim2, channels)
data = tf.reshape(data, [1, 200, 2, 2, 1])
```

`data` will look something like this:

[image]

Now, I want to perform something similar to `MaxPooling2D((2,2))` operation on `data` to get only `c` (as it has the highest amplitude). Clearly, we cannot use `MaxPooling3D` and `TimeDistributed` layers directly, as they will perform pooling at each timestep. I tried my luck with alternatives using `tf.math.reduce_max()` and `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax` but they were not straight-forward.

Any suggestions or comments is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation for the above question,

```
def temporal_max_pooler(signal_stack):

  #signal_stack (bs, T, f, f, d)
  overall_stack = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
  for ch in range(signal_stack.shape[-1]):
    ch_signals = signal_stack[:,:,:,:,ch:ch+1]
    patches = tf.extract_volume_patches(ch_signals, (1, 1, 2, 2, 1), 
                                        (1, 1, 2, 2, 1), 'VALID')
    patches = tf.transpose(patches, [0, 1, 4, 2, 3])
    (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4) = patches.shape
    patches = tf.reshape(patches, [s0, s1, s2//2, s2//2, s4*s3])
    ch_stack = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for p in range(patches.shape[-1]):
      p_signals = tf.reshape(patches[:,:,:,:,p],
                             (patches.shape[0], patches.shape[1], -1))
      max_amps = tf.math.reduce_max(p_signals, 1)
      where_is_max = tf.math.argmax(max_amps, -1)
      winners = tf.gather(p_signals, where_is_max, axis=-1, batch_dims=1)
      ch_stack.write(ch_stack.size(), winners)
    ch_stack = tf.transpose(ch_stack.stack(), [1, 2, 0])
    n_d = tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(ch_stack.shape[-1], 'float32'))
    n_d = tf.cast(n_d, 'int32')
    ch_stack = tf.reshape(ch_stack, [ch_stack.shape[0], ch_stack.shape[1],
                                     n_d, n_d])
    overall_stack.write(overall_stack.size(), ch_stack)
  overall_stack = overall_stack.stack()
  return tf.transpose(overall_stack, [1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
```